# How to replace slashes that do not come after “<”

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a string that looks like this `<span>hey</span>/<span>bye</span>/<span>why</span>/`. How would I use `preg_replace` to substitute all the non-HTML-tag `/`s with `::` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using negative lookbehind for this:

```
$pattern = '#(?<!<)/#';
$replacement = '::';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
```

The gist of this is that it will only replace `/` where the preceding character is not `<`

Of course you might need to go a step further and make sure it doesn't have a following character of `>`, such as would be the case with self-closing tags.  In that case, you could add a negative lookahead as well such that the pattern becomes:

```
$pattern = '#(?<!<)/(?!>)#';
```

Comment: I just posted this same answer :-)

Comment: *clap* *clap* *clap*
was watching thread ... you posted after Mike